# Homotopy group of maps into S^3 using its Lie group multiplication to define the group operation

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, homotopy-theory, lie-groups

The Bruschlinsky group of maps of a space X into S<sup>1</sup> up to homotopy, using the multiplication on S<sup>1</sup>, is well-known to equal the first cohomology group of X (at least assuming X is a reasonably nice space).

What is known about the analogous group of homotopy classes of maps of X into S<sup>3</sup>, with the group operation defined using the Lie group multiplication of S<sup>3</sup> ? Denote this group of homotopy classes by g(X, S<sup>3</sup>).

In particular: If X is S<sup>n</sup>, is it possible for g(S<sup>n</sup>, S<sup>3</sup>) to be non-abelian?  More generally, are sufficient conditions on X known for g(X, S<sup>3</sup>) to be non-abelian? Is there any standard reference about such groups?

Comment: If X is a suspension, then g(X, S^3) is abelian by the Hilton-Eckmann argument.  In particular, g(S^n, S^3) = \pi_n(S^3) is abelian for all n.

Comment: Usually the group is denoted $\pi^3(X)$. It's abelian if $X$ is complex of dimension $\leq 5$. On the other hand, $\pi^3(S^3\times S^3)=g(S^3\times S^3,S^3)$ is nonabelian.

Comment: @Tyrone Do theses groups have a name ?

Comment: @OlivierBégassat $\pi^k(X)$ is called cohomotopy if I remember correctly. It can be given a group structure if $X$ has an associative comultiplication with inverse or $S^k$ has an associative multiplication with inverse.

Comment: @JohnRognes is it obvious that the group laws coincide on $g(S^n,S^3)=\pi_n(S^3)$? The first one is induced by the law on $S^3$ while the second one relies on something (some co-law?) on $S^n$.

Comment: @YCor Yes, the H-space structure on S^3 = \Omega HP^\infty and the co-H-space structure on S^n = \Sigma S^{n-1} distribute over one another, hence induce the same pairing, and this is commutative.  This is the Hilton-Eckmann argument.  See e.g. Thm. 1.6.8 in Spanier's Algebraic Topology.